# Why is $(T-2I)^3(v_2) = 0$ for $i=2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose that $T$ is a linear operator on $\mathbb{C^8}$, and $\beta$ = $\{v_1,v_2,...v_8\}$ is an ordered basis for $\mathbb{C^8}$ such that
>
> $J = [T]_{\beta} =$ $$
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>     2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
>     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>     \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>
> Since $v_1$ and $v_4$ are eigenvectors of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda= 2$, it follows that $(T-2I)^3(v_i) = 0$ for $i = 1,2,3,$ and $4$

I want to make sure that I've gotten the reasoning completely correct.

As an example, since $T(v_2) = v_1 + 2v_2$, it follows that $(T-2I)(v_2) = v_1$. So, $(T-2I)^2(v_1) = 0$, and then we can multiply $(T-2I)^2(v_1) = 0$ by $(T-2I)(v_2) = v_1$ to get

$(T-2I)(v_2)(T-2I)^2(v_1) = v_1*0$

and divide both sides by $(v_1)$ so that

$(T-2I)^3(v_2) = 0$ for $i=2$ ?

Comment: You can't divide by a vector.

Comment: That's true but how would I get $(T - 2I)^3(v_2) = 0$ for $i=2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first steps are correct:
$$
(T - 2I)v_2 = v_1.
$$
Now, lets just compute what we seek to find!
$$
(T - 2I)^3 v_2 = (T - 2I) (T - 2I) v_1 = (T - 2I)(Tv_1 - 2v_1) = (T - 2I)(0) = 0
$$